# How to specify class imported from Swift

Tags: swift, cocoapods

In Swift 5 the standard library includes `Result` object for passing success failure blocks. However `Apollo` also has a `Result` class and the file imports Apollo. Is there a way to specify which `Result` the code is referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Swift.Result` or `Apollo.Result` to specify.